# Is it expected that the doc intelligence studio labelling tool only returning 2 pages of extracted value?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I try to train a custom extraction model in Azure Document Intelligence Studio on an around 10 pages document.

In their sample labeling tool, I can see the first 2 pages having the OCR extracted value for ease of labeling.

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLCAg.png)]

However, from every document's 3th page onwards, no OCR extracted value is being visualized.

[image]

Is this an expected behaviour of the labeling tool? Such that I need to draw the labeling region myself?

Comment: I think I might get the reason. When using free tier, I have generated the OCR result json file into the same blob folder. I switched to standard pricing afterward, however the labeling tool doesn't allow to re-generate the OCR result. Once I deleted the OCR json files under the same blob folder, I can re-generate the OCR result with more values in the rest of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an expected behaviour of the labeling tool? Such that I need to draw the labeling region myself?

- ***There is a difference in the capabilities or limitations of the OCR extraction process. It's possible that the standard pricing tier introduced restrictions or modified settings that affected the OCR extraction beyond the second page.***

Here, I have created document intelligence with standard pricing and that makes the difference in the limitation.

[image]

Here I have uploaded a dummy document to test the service which has 6 pages. I started analysis to check the content.

[image]

- It can also detect tables, fields, figures also and we can draw manually by labelling.

[image]

**Third pages :**

[image]

[image]